# Disallowing AJAX as a security feature

Tags: ajax

I have a page that relys on several AJAX functions.  Are there any common security configurations that disallow AJAX?

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off javascript. That will remove the J from the equation.

Comment: I know you can turn JavaScript off, but does are there any common configurations where AJAX wouldn't work?

Comment: Ummm ... Javascript turned off by default is a common security configuration; e.g. using the NoScript plugin on FireFox.

Answer (score 2):

See:

[Is it possible to disable AJAX without disabling JavaScript completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272541/is-it-possible-to-disable-ajax-without-disabling-javascript-completely)

Answer (score 1):

In configurations where Javascript is disabled on the client you need to have a fallback that will work without AJAX.

Comment: Is there any good reason for turning off JavaScript?  If not, I'm happy if the page just doesn't work if they don't have it.

Comment: If your end user is blind; I don't think screen-readers like Jaws do much with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Not any very common configurations I'm aware of.

NoScript users, and users who disable JavaScript more broadly, are probably your largest group.

Some more paranoid large corporates might disable JavaScript by default in IE using Group Policy, but it's not common (and decreasingly so).

Some of the newer security products (including smarter web proxies and desktop AV products) will attempt deeper inspection of the content passing over them, including trying to look for malice in JavaScript; if you upset one of these, it might fail in strange ways. But again, should be fine in the vast majority of cases.